# Power BI Desktop.. Automatic Refresh and Published

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

I am rather new to Power BI, but I think I have a rather simple question.

Power BI is connected to Google BigQuery through import. Within PowerBI I make some transformations to create my visualisations. These visualisations create a report.

I publish the report and can then find it on https://app.powerbi.com/ in my Power BI environment.

The data in Google BigQuery is updated daily. Can I update the report online automatically without me having to press refresh in Power BI desktop? As the data gets updated automatically and I will not be changing the visualisations daily, I would think this is achievable.

If the answer is yes, how might I achieve this in the most simplest of terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. It is called [scheduled refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh). After publishing your report to Power BI Service, go to [`Settings` -> `Datasets`](https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/settings/datasets?noSignUpCheck=1), select your dataset in the list, enter the credentials under `Data source credentials` section (if needed), and then configure the settings under `Scheduled refresh` section:

[image]